# I have the error: "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" - spring 3.1.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am setting up an api gateway with Spring Cloud Gateway. But I only get "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" as an answer.

For example with this configuration I get the error:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeExchange(authorize -> authorize
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

My properties:

```
server:
  port: 3802

logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.type: TRACE
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:3800/eureka
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  application:
    name: gateway-service-nixbuy
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: user-service
          uri: lb://api/user-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
```

If I use spring boot version 2.7.17 everything seems to work fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: please enable debug logs and edit your question to include your full debug logs

Comment: Can you provide a `springSecurityFilterChain` that was before migration, and also a question it was all the staff that you have been changed ?  I mean security migration

Comment: @AndreiLisa It is the same springSecurityFilterChain in the previous version.  The only difference between 3.1.0 and 2.7.17 is that in the pom.xml I am changing the version of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud.  The rest of the code stays exactly the same and still 2.7.17 works and 3.1.0  doesn't

Comment: @dur You're right! adding `@Configuration` above `@EnableWebFluxSecurity`  worked! It seems like it's something from spring boot 3 because before, @EnableWebFluxSecurity was enough. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `@Configuration` to your class, see [Configuration Migrations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#add-configuration-annotation):

> **Add @Configuration annotation**
>
> In 6.0, `@Configuration` is removed from `@EnableWebSecurity`, `@EnableMethodSecurity`, `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`, and `@EnableGlobalAuthentication`.
>
> To prepare for this, wherever you are using one of these annotations, you may need to add `@Configuration`. For example, `@EnableMethodSecurity` changes from:
>
> ```java
> @EnableMethodSecurity
> public class MyConfiguration {
>   // ...
> }
> ```
>
> [,,,]
>
> to:
>
> ```java
> @Configuration
> @EnableMethodSecurity
> public class MyConfiguration {
>   // ...
> }
> ```